# Scala, ZIO, Json - how to deserialize circe json response?

Tags: json, scala, circe, zio, zio-json

I have a strange problem with deserialization from external service. I have some lib where I call method and pass params. This method always returns `zio.IO[Error, Value]`.
Inside this lib some magic happens, it connects with other service, get response and return it to me. I create a simple `for comprehension` example, where I call this method:

```
for {
  response <- library.someMethod(firstParam, secondParam).map(value => value.code).mapError(error => showError(error))
} yield response
```

`Error` and `Value` here `zio.IO[Error, Value]` are some custom objects. When I ran this `for comprehension` code, I got an error, connected with serialization:

```
The Either on which value was invoked was not defined as a Right; it was Left(sttp.client3.DeserializationException: expected json value got 'Intern...' (line 1, column 1)).
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: The Either on which value was invoked was not defined as a Right; it was Left(sttp.client3.DeserializationException: expected json value got 'Intern...' (line 1, column 1)).
    at org.scalatest.EitherValues$Valuable.value(EitherValues.scala:211)
```

I'm not sure if I need additional decoders or I should change something in for comprehension code to deserialize this value and error? Is it possible to deserialize response and take value correctly?

Comment: You didn't show us `someMethod`, how does it parse? What's the input data? Look's like you have a plain text but not JSON.

Comment: To be more specific, instead of some json doc like `{}`, `123`, `[1,2,3]`, or `"foo"` you have `Intern...` which isn't a valid start of a json doc.